# pinescript to draw horizontal lines (Support and Resistance) based on input

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I generate levels from my other methods, want to draw them in trading view.  Trying below with comma separated values but getting error.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Support and Resistance Levels", overlay=true)

// Define support and resistance levels
supportLevels = [4125, 4115, 4089.5, 4085.5, 4062.25, 4070.5, 4105.5]
resistanceLevels = [4163.5, 4171.25, 4191.5, 4203.25, 4209.75, 4246.25

// Define line styles
supportLineStyle = line.style_dashed
resistanceLineStyle = line.style_solid

// Plot support levels
for i = 0 to (array.size(supportLevels) - 1)
    line.new(x1=bar_index-200, y1=supportLevels[i], x2=bar_index, y2=supportLevels[i], color=color.green, style=supportLineStyle)

// Plot resistance levels
for i = 0 to (array.size(resistanceLevels) - 1)
    line.new(x1=bar_index-200, y1=resistanceLevels[i], x2=bar_index, y2=resistanceLevels[i], color=color.red, style=resistanceLineStyle)
```

Tried changing to constant values still getting Syntax error at input '['

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript you can't adress array like this.
See this pinescript manual page for a complete explanation about arrays :
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html?highlight=array

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change your array syntax. Here is your code with the correct way to use arrays.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Support and Resistance Levels", overlay=true)

// Define support and resistance levels
var supportLevels = array.from(4125, 4115, 4089.5, 4085.5, 4062.25, 4070.5, 4105.5)
var resistanceLevels =  array.from(4163.5, 4171.25, 4191.5, 4203.25, 4209.75, 4246.25)

// Define line styles
supportLineStyle = line.style_dashed
resistanceLineStyle = line.style_solid

// Plot support levels
for i = 0 to (supportLevels.size() - 1)
    line.new(x1=bar_index-200, y1=supportLevels.get(i), x2=bar_index, y2=supportLevels.get(i), color=color.green, style=supportLineStyle)

// Plot resistance levels
for i = 0 to (resistanceLevels.size() - 1)
    line.new(x1=bar_index-200, y1=resistanceLevels.get(i), x2=bar_index, y2=resistanceLevels.get(i), color=color.red, style=resistanceLineStyle)
```